# Heroku and bundler version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I'm pushing code on Heroku as usual.

But this message appear :

> Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the
>   version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to
>   the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.

So I run:

```
heroku run gem install bundler
```

> Running gem install bundler on ⬢ myapp... up, run.3401
>   (Standard-1X)
>
> Fetching: bundler-1.16.1.gem (100%)
>
> Successfully installed bundler-1.16.1
>
> Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.1
>
> Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.16.1
>
> Done installing documentation for bundler after 11 seconds
>
> 1 gem installed

But when I retry to push code:

> `heroku run bundle install`
>
> Running bundle install on ⬢ myapp... up, run.9532 (Standard-1X)
>
> Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the
>   version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to
>   the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.

In the gem Gemfile.lock I got:

> BUNDLED WITH
>      1.16.1

I don't understand why this bundler release doesn't want to be install on Heroku.

Comment: Did you read Heroku's [Bundler Version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version) article?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bundler `1.15.2` is the version that is pre-installed on Heroku dynos. Changing Bundler to `1.16.1` on your machine doesn't change the version installed on Heroku.

Furthermore, you cannot update Bundler on Heroku by running `bundle install`. And even if that was possible it would take effect on the next run of Bundler - and usually, you only bundle once on a Heroku dyno.

My advice is: It is just a warning, just ignore it and let's hope that Heroku updates Bundler more ofter in the future.

Comment: You can only change the heroku bundler via custom buildpack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115171/upgrading-bundler-version-on-heroku?rq=1

Comment: fyi Heroku now uses  bundler 1.17.3, at least they do on the Heroku-18 stack, it might be stack-dependent

Answer (score 0):

You also want to make sure you're using a standard Heroku buildpack for this.

When I attempted to upgrade my app from Cedar to Heroku-20, it kept failing with this same bundler error. But, eventually, I remembered that I had install a custom buildback and that turned out to be the source of the incorrect bundler version.

Once I switched back to the default Heroku Ruby buildpack, I was finally able to deploy without any issues.